# Какие учебники русского языка нам нужны?

Tags: методика

Почему русскому человеку сложно изучать свой родной язык? Вот некоторые МНЕНИЯ: «Изучение родного русского в школе похоже на заучивание латыни». «Необходимая грамматика превращается в невероятное занудство, которое может выдержать не каждый школьник». «Львиная доля времени идет на изучение правописания,  а это лишь отражение языка на письме.  На изучение самого языка времени не остается».

Так что же делать?  Наверное, ничего нельзя сделать – так велика проблема, зависящая от очень многих составляющих. Мне кажется, что ДОЛЖНО СОВЕРШИТЬСЯ ЧУДО. Придет некто умный, знающий, имеющий власть, отодвинет в сторону чиновников-бюрократов, уберет старые учебники (по словам академика РАН, «бессмысленные, косноязычные, расплывчатые, противоречивые, с устаревшими или просто неверными изречениями») и положит перед нами учебник новый. А каким вы видите этот учебник?

С моей точки зрения, пусть это будет набор/пакет учебников.  Вот, например, совсем тонкая книжка (100-150 стр.), по которой школьники  будут учиться с 6-го по 11-й класс. Одна на все шесть лет, одинаковая для учащихся школ и абитуриентов! В нем разделы: фонетика, грамматика, орфография, пунктуация, теория текста.   Здесь изложена информация: краткая, точная,  на современном уровне, это СПРАВОЧНИК ПО ТЕОРИИ, и   для такого учебника нужен хороший конкурс. Остальные учебники с практическими заданиями  – для каждого класса.

И еще несколько пожеланий:

1)  Изучение языка – это не только изучение правописания, это, прежде всего, направленная РАБОТА С ТЕКСТАМИ различного стиля, анализ образцов и написание собственных работ,  а также  РАЗВИТИЕ  УСТНОЙ РЕЧИ, умение правильно, точно, убедительно, образно излагать свои мысли в различных ситуациях.

2) Ученик должен быть соучастником процесса образования. Очень утомительно просто слушать, понимать, запоминать, нужно дать ему возможность делать собственные выводы.

3) Без грамматики знание языка невозможно, и грамматика может быть ИНТЕРЕСНОЙ. Давайте вспомним природу интереса: нам неинтересно, когда мы ничего не знаем о предмете и когда (условно) знаем всё, то есть не слышим ничего нового. Максимум положительных эмоций приходится, кажется, где-то на 1/3 от нулевой точки.

4) И не надо беречь головы школьников от будто бы сложных терминов и понятий – они способны на много большее, чем им предлагается (вспомним, что развитие  возможно только под нагрузкой). Просто при изучении грамматики мы наблюдаем нулевой контакт интереса (не предвидится  новых открытий и творческой работы), соответственно,  результат также близок к нулю.

Comment: Странно, что никто не ответил. Такой ведь учебник есть, так и называется: 

Русский язык. Теория. 5-9 классы. Бабайцева В.В, Чеснокова Л.Д...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы написать хороший учебник по любому предмету, нужно понимать, что мы хотим добиться в конце, после изучения материала.

В 10-11 классе на уроках русского и литературы мы занимались примерно по вашему плану. Каждый месяц мы писали большое сочинение и помимо этого 1-2 раза в неделю устное мини-сочинение, которое мы должны были зачитать перед классом. Теоретически устное сочинение можно было произнести и без подготовки, но в реальности хотя бы на уровне 4-ки сочинять на ходу могли лишь пара человек из класса, и то уже в 11 классе. Также большое внимание уделялось анализу текстов, на предмет стиля и тропов и формированию правильной устной речи.
Достоинством такой системы стало то, что  никакого отвращения к русскому языку у меня нет, я без труда могу говорить как по писанному и во время учёбы в вузе за счёт развитой устной речи мог "отбрехаться" на экзамене, даже если не знал билет.
Недостатком подобного подхода явилось то, что за два года обучения в старшей школе моя орфография и пунктуация не улучшились ни на йоту, также как и у всех остальных учеников. Не уверен, что подобная методика будет способствовать хорошей сдаче ЕГЭ, но когда я учился его ещё не ввели. Трое учеников из класса по окончанию школы поступило на филфак.

Ваша методика будет способствовать формированию хорошей речи, но снизит успехи в орфографии и пунктуации. Думаю, учитывая то, что в орфографии компьютер уже способен устранить процентов 80 ошибок (с пунктуацией хуже, но цифры всё равно будут расти), то изучать возможности построения фразы ученику было бы полезнее, чем правила и исключения из них.

Comment: Получается, что методики развития письменной и устной речи уже существуют и проявили себя с хорошей стороны. К 10-11 классу изучение правописания должно быть закончено, и к нему следует обращаться при необходимости в индивидуальном порядке. Но учебники по орфографии/пунктуации в 6-9 классах должны принципиально измениться, чтобы обеспечить высокую эффективность при минимальных временных затратах. Если этого не будет, то ничего не изменится, времени на изучение языка как такового не будет.

Comment: Это должен быть базовый вариант без подробного изучения всех существующих исключений, но дающий возможность грамотно записать собственную речь. И к ЕГЭ надо начинать готовится с 6-ого класса, а не в последний год обучения.

Comment: Тут нужно понимать, что это был гуманитарный класс, в который чтобы попасть необходимо было пройти через конкурс (из 35 желающих 10 отсеяли). У нас в неделю было 6 литературы и 2 русского, так что учительнице было где разгуляться, хотя даже при увеличенном объёме часов мы по литературе успели дойти только до писателей-деревенщиков и Высоцкого, оставив за рамками школьного курса Бродского, поэтов-шестидесятников и современных писателей.

Answer (score 2):

Почему русскому человеку сложно изучать свой родной язык?
А думаете, английскому человеку проще изучать свой родной язык? А китайскому человеку?
А почему, собссно, должно быть легко? Почему всё должно быть шоколадно, я вас спрашиваю? А математику изучать тоже должно быть легко?

Comment: Совершенно  верно.

Comment: Труд полезен для человека, но только не сизифов труд. Труд не должен быть легким, но и не обязан походить на укладывание кирпичей. И он должен иметь результат, только тогда человек испытывает положительные эмоции. Заучивание без понимания, без интереса к предмету является неэффективным и даже вредным.

Comment: Почему мы должны плохо изъясняться на родном языке и безграмотно писать. Почему нам твердят бесконечное "надо запомнить", и ничего не объясняют, и сочиняют всё новые правила. Самое дорогое у человека - это его время, и он имеет право на его разумное использование. Что касается математики, то там легче, там развивают ваши мозги, а не не заставляют заучивать решение задач наизусть.

Comment: У-у... А конкретику привести можете? Вот у меня, помню, учительница не утвердила бесконечные "надо запомнить", и у дочки в школе тоже. И не сочиняла новые правила. Это, пардон, у вас просто истерика какая-то...

Comment: Смешное слово - истерика. Это возбуждённая, лихорадочная, судорожная деятельность в каком-л. направлении. Вы именно это хотели сказать? А теперь о конкретике. У нас вообще есть правила, которые объясняются, а не запоминаются? Наши дети могут четко рассказать, почему ЧА-ЩА пишется через А, или хотя бы почему мы  безударные гласные проверяем? Или вот в слове "дождь" почему не проверяем букву Ж? И в слове "вензель" почему не пишем Ь? А декабрьский/январский запомнить надо, или можно объяснить? Так что теперь за Вами очередь. Приведите пример правила с объяснением, которое заучивать не надо.

Comment: Конечно, могут. Но разумеется, не все дети. Когда-то было по-другому?
Про морфологический принцип русской грамматики дети знают, даже если не знают, как он называется. Про то, что Ч и Щ когда-то были твердыми, дети тоже знают. Дождь – дожди. Так низзя проверить?

А к чему вы клоните-то? Вы давеча говорили про кучу "новых правил" – где они? Это раз. А второе – вы предлагаете убрать силовым методом все т.наз."исключения"? В угоду дебилам? Но это не удастся. Как вы это представляете-то конкретно?
Так что, пардон, истерика продолжается.. ))

Comment: Все шипящие  (Ж, Ш, Ч, Щ) когда-то были мягкие. Буква Ж в слове дожди всегда находится в слабой позиции по звонкости/глухости и не проверяется. В 1956 году все  Правила пунктуации помещались на 45 страницах, теперь это солидные учебники. (И это понятно: решаются новые задачи, и все эти решения также предлагается выучить). При изложении учебного материала не надо базовую часть смешивать с частными исключениями, которые несопоставимы по значимости. Этим исключениям место в справочниках, а не в учебниках.

Comment: Замечательно. Выходит, вы знаете. Но считаете, что детям это трудно, и их надо избавить... ЖИ и ШИ не запомнить!!!

Кстати, сейчас действуют ещё правила 1956 года, не думаю, что вы этого не знаете. И не думаю, что не можете отличить учебник русского языка от документа, который называется "Правила..." Или первоклассникам надо прямо Правила раздать, и пусть штудируют?!

Ага, об исключениях не будем упоминать... Пожалеем детский моск... Интересно, где это вы таких дебильных детей видите, что так их жалеете?
Нормальным детям вполне по силам усвоить школьную грамматику. Да, это непросто – и что?

Comment: А по мне, просто. За 10 лет русский язык на весьма неплохом уровне может выучить не-носитель. И сдать ЕГЭ. Кстати, я смотрел лекцию одного преподавателя РКИ — лектор говорила, что у неё все ученики сдают. Так что встаёт вопрос: а что такое на уроках учат все эти дети, для которых русский родной (часто единственный) язык, на котором они, к тому же, каждый день общаются? Нельзя ли выучить русский язык за 3-4 года, а освободившееся время посвятить, не знаю, китайскому что ли? У нас ведь относительно простая орфография — прямое следствие того, что последний раз она обновлялась меньше 100 лет наза

Comment: Вы путаете изучение родного языка и языка как иностранного. Абсолютно разные вещи. А если на языке начинает говорить ребёнок, то нельзя сказать, что он неноситель. А взрослому неносителю за 10 лет наш ЕГЭ сдать невозможно.

Comment: Не вижу связи между ребёнком и носителем. Я себя не причисляю к носителям английского, хотя у нас он ещё в 6 лет пошёл. И путаницы никакой нет — я просто провожу параллель между этими совсем разными по сложности процессами. Орфография и пунктуация явно не стоят потраченного времени, а причастия и деепричастия — капля в море. Есть ли разница в результате, я не знаю. Например, у нас последние 3 года этого предмета не было. Кто-то же вложил в обучение ещё лишних 200 часов. Спрашивается, а цель какая? Не хотят же, в самом деле, просто освоить лишнее время.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы написать картину, надо знать и уметь очень многое: краски и способы их приготовления, кисти и особенности пользования ими,тонкости смешения цветов и т д. и т. д. - очень многое по сравнению с перечисленным. Без знания профессиональных тонкостей хорошую картину, думаю, написать невозможно. Но есть самородки, которые изнутри себя, по наитию правильно выбирают нужное, кажется, без труда. Итак, одному надо учиться - долго, настойчиво, всю жизнь, а другому это дано от Бога. К чему я это говорю? К тому, что картина - это, образно говоря, литература, а всё остальное, необходимое писателю, - это русский язык (если отбросить ещё более важное - знание самой жизни). Зачем отлично знать русский язык в отрыве от литературы? Незачем. Правильно говорить, правильно писать - это своего рода снобизм, которым амбициозные люди хотят отделиться от всей массы и снисходительно оценивать возможности  других. Русский язык, сам по себе, не воспитывает, формирует человека литература. Надо знать набор основных правил русского языка, о перечне которых можно, в принципе, договориться и - написать такую книгу, которая удовлетворила бы и Софию в том числе. Можно быть гением знания русского языка? Нет. А гением литературы - вполне. Вот как-то так - сказал бы (уж забыл, кто из нас так любит заканчивать свои комментарии). Мнение спорное, но мы и приходим сюда затем, чтобы, в отличие от Галактиона, найти истину (ну не обижайтесь, Галактион, - я шучу!)

Comment: Дорогой.

Вы и подобные Вам лица приходите сюда за "уважением".

Comment: >> Правильно говорить, правильно писать - это своего рода снобизм, которым амбициозные люди хотят отделиться от всей массы и снисходительно оценивать возможности других

Совершенно верно, отделиться от. Точнее, выделиться из! Разница большая Видите, вы не шибко хорошо знаете язык.
Только это не снобизм, а то мы снобизмом назовём и модную одежду, и дома, и автомобили, и т.д. и т.п.
А вы придете, допустим, к портному заказывать брюки и увидите объявление типа "Штанов нет" или "Чясы роботы з двух до сими" – вы будете у него шить или пойдете к другому? Ась? Ну вы и сноб... )))

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я тоже люблю сравнивать литературу с живописью, у них много общего: там краски, здесь слова. И с музыкой литературу также можно сравнить. Но всем видам искусства нужна школа: музыкант играет гаммы, художник пишет этюды, и все учатся, прежде чем окончательно раскрыть перед нами свой талант. Вы правы, самородки чувствуют язык. Но писатель гениальный должен быть и писателем искусным, именно этот термин употребляет Пушкин. А Ломоносов считал: " В России словесные науки не дадут никогда прийти в упадок российскому слову".

Comment: Грамматика - это строй языка. Не напишешь симфонию, не зная нот, если даже музыка звучит в твоей душе. И вот еще пара пушкинских цитат: Знаки препинания существуют, чтобы "выделить мысль, привести слова в правильное соотношение и дать фразе легкость и правильное звучание". "Истинный вкус состоит не в безотчетном отвержении такого-то слова, такого-то оборота, но в чувстве соразмерности и сообразности". Вот соразмерность и сообразность и надо изучать на уроках русского языка на примерах нашей изящной словесности

Answer (score 1):

Нам нужен учебник с приложением английского словаря в кириллице. Дети сразу должны учить будущий, новый, кривативный "русский" язык.

Comment: Кривативный язык - это великолепая находка для характеристики современного падения - не языка! - кривативных "русских" людей!

Comment: Наличие англицизмов в русском языке - очень даже хорошее явление: язык обогащается за счёт заимствованной лексики.

Comment: Утешил, называется! В нашем компьютерном русском языке почти нет русского языка, он едва ли не весь кривативный!

Comment: @Tagirix Не устану повторять для людей, не владеющих иностранными языками: ТОЛЬКО в "русском" языке, и особенно в компьютерном, почти нет русского языка. В других языках (я тут их перечислял уже раз 25) только свои родные слова. "Обогащается", а точнее деградирует ТОЛЬКО русский язык. Если это "хорошее явление", тогда Вы себя ставите в один ряд с папуасами и пигмеями.

Answer (score 0):

1. Вопрос "Почему русскому человеку сложно изучать свой родной язык?" похож на вопрос "Почему в России русским всегда жилось хуже, чем другим?".
2. Вопрос "Почему в России русским всегда жилось хуже, чем другим?" сформулирован Пeтром Хомяковым в предисловии к его книге "Россия против Руси".

Значительное число правил правописания на так называемом "русском языке" предназначены для того, чтобы сформировать комплекс неполноценности у ученика и, в конечном итоге, превратить ученика в скотину.

Пример

Если во время диктанта ученик запишет предложение "Рыцарь снял панцирь и надел чёрный шёлковый халат и шерстяные носки." так, как он слышит это предложение (то есть в виде "Рыцарь снял панцырь и надел чорный шолковый халат и шэрстяные носки."), тогда школьная работница  объявит, что этот ученик не умеет писать на русском языке. Разумеется, школьная работница врёт, бо:

- предложение "Рыцарь снял панцырь и надел чорный шолковый халат и шэрстяные носки." написано по-русски,
- предложение "Рыцарь снял панцирь и надел чёрный шёлковый халат и шерстяные носки." написано по-советски.

Comment: Я не совсем поняла Ваш ответ. Вы считаете, что учебники грамматики  и методики, по которым сложно учиться, - это результат несовершенства всей государственной системы или даже нечто преднамеренное? Какая здесь непосредственная причинно-следственная связь?

Comment: Я не сомневаюсь, что "учебники грамматики и методики, по которым сложно учиться, - это ... нечто преднамеренное".

Comment: А мне кажется, что бюрократический аппарат чисто из меркантильных соображений не дает шансов для продвижения и развития орфографической и педагогической науки. Вот сейчас ставится вопрос о создании единого учебника русского языка, но вряд ли что-то в нем изменится. Талантливых лингвистов с новыми идеями вряд ли и близко подпустят, а свои люди уже, наверное, подсчитывают барыши. Будем считать, что во всём виноваты коррумпированные чиновники и начнем с ними бороться.

Comment: Я не возражаю, чтобы Вы руководствовались тем, что Вам кажется. Например, Вам может показаться, что барин - хороший, а бурмистр - плохой.

Comment: Наши бурмистры при любом барине - и хорошем, и плохом, и всяком -  почему-то одни и те же, то есть плохие. Так может быть, баре тут ни при чем, а что-то в этих бурмистрах есть постоянно порочное.

Comment: Может быть, ... а может и не быть.

Comment: Вы, София, провоцируете своим странным вопросом таких вот личностей, как этот Галактион. Вот и получайте такую хрень: "нечто преднамеренное", " комплекс неполноценности", "Россия против Руси" и проч.

Comment: Галактион, а почему ученик написал "шэрстяные носки", "рыцарь", там же редукция Э/Ы и А/Ы, надо писать "шырстяные, рыцырь". Ч - мягкий звук, почему написано О? Так что в любом случае (при фонетическом или фонематическом письме) двойка ему обеспечена.

Comment: Ученик написал "шэрстяные носки", потому что ученик произносит слово "шэрстяные" с ударением на первый слог.

Ученик написал "рыцарь", потому что ученик слышит звук [a] и в слоге "царь", и в слове "царь", и в слове "цари".